# Multiple arrows to an object

Tags: arrows

I am trying to figure out how to make several arrows point to a particular object. For example if I am wanting to have an arrow `$A_i \rightarrow A` `A_j \rightarrow A$` and `$A_k \rightarrow A$` and `$A_i \rightarrow A_j$` in a diagram. I have worked out how to do:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix@C+2em@R+2em{
   A_i  \ar[d]_{f^{i}} & B_i \ar[d]^{h^{i}} \\
  A \ar[r]_{\phi} & B
  }
 \end{equation*}
```

But I don't know how to modify this to get what I want (and I can't seem to find examples using the `equation*` or other workable examples.

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: It would be useful to have a MWE.  I have no idea what `\ar` or `\xymatrix@C+2em@R+2em` are about.  It looks like you're trying to use `\xymatrix@C` as a macro, but that's generally not a valid macro naming convention in the body of a document.

Comment: Can you please add to your question an image of the desired output? It's not clear from the code snippet you posted the desired position for the objects and arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the more modern [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package, you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A_i  
  \ar{dr}[swap]{f^{i}} 
  \ar{r}{h} 
& 
A_j
  \ar{d}[swap]{f^{j}} 
& 
A_k  
  \ar{dl}{f^{k}} \\
& A
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}
A_i  
  \ar{dr}{f^{i}} 
  \ar{d}[swap]{h}  \\ 
A_j\ar{r}[swap]{f^{j}} & A
  \\
A_k  
  \ar{ur}[swap]{f^{k}} \\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo. Is it using the the tikz-cd package that makes this more of a modern approach? I have seen it around, thanks for the example using it! What are the benefits of using this package as opposed to the {all}[xy]?

Comment: @user1922184 `tikz-cd` allows you to use all the power of [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/PGF), so yes, `tikz-cd` it's a more modern and versatile package for commutative diagrams.

Comment: I put this as the answer because it uses tikz-cd and the [all]{xy} wasn't working so well.

Comment: Also, after some amounts of messing around with the tikz pdf examples here: http://www.jmilne.org/not/Mtikz.pdf  I am wondering.. what if I want to change the right arrow i.e. \arrow{r} to an implies $\Leftrightarrow$? Now your example works great and I am trying to not have to use the examples in the article using \path as it seems to be a whole different format which is quite more complicated. So is there a abbreviation for the iff? Even better, could I somehow use your example and just include latex directly in ie. such as the $\Leftrightarrow$ mentioned?

Comment: @user1922184 Refer to the `tikz-cd` package documentation to see the different type of arrows already available. You can use `\Leftrightarrow` directly, as in `\begin{tikzcd}
A\ar[r,Leftrightarrow] & B
\end{tikzcd}`

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo. While I hadn't found such simplicity in just typing arrows, I went on a mission to find a reference (you had to get your info from somewhere). For those who need it, here is documentation: http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf

Note on Page 3-4, the usage of, for example: \arrow[ddr, bend right, "y"].  One would have the bent arrow as well as the label "y".  Thanks again.

Comment: It might be a bug but any idea on how to get the vertical $LeftRightarrow$, as of now, only the ends of the arrows (looks like vertical less than and greater than signs) show up. I have been trying to experiment with rotating this arrow but don't see how to get it to connect to nodes $A$ and $B$. I have:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,.5) {$A$};
\node (B) at (0,-.5) {$B$};
\node at (0,0) {\rotatebox{270}{$\Leftrightarrow$}};
\path[->,font=\scriptsize,>=angle 90];
\end{tikzpicture}  I know I am redefining nodes and B but don't know how to connect with the initial A and B in the figure.

Comment: @user1922184 please feel free to open a fresh new question.

Comment: I will do that, didn't know if I should dedicate one to it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix@C+2em@R+2em{
   A_i \ar[r]^{\phi} \ar[dr]_{f^{i}} & A_j \ar[d]^{f^{j}} & A_k \ar[dl]^{f^{k}} \\
   & A 
  }
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

or

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \xymatrix@C+2em@R+2em{
   A_i \ar[d]_{\phi} \ar[dr]^{f^{i}} \\
   A_j \ar[r]^{f^{j}} & A \\
   A_k \ar[ur]_{f^{k}}
  }
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm completely unfamiliar with this package `xy`.  And `texdoc xy` doesn't really pull up much useful about things like `\xymatrix....`.  Where do I go to find documentation?

Comment: @A.Ellett http://xy-pic.sourceforge.net/ and go to the documenation section.

Comment: @A.Ellett `texdoc xypic`